# Disable Vimium in Chrome w/ shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, vimium

How to disable / enable Vimium in Chrome with simple keyboard shortcut? Trying to avoid using the mouse. :)

For example, in Vim for Visual studio, the entire Vim can be toggled on/off with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd>, handy in Chrome where some pages have shortcuts, that Vim interfers with.

Pop-up help (<kbd>?</kbd>) doesnt helpt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a shortcut for that. What you could do is to use the [SimpleExtManager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simpleextmanager/kniehgiejgnnpgojkdhhjbgbllnfkfdk), to assign the keyboard shortcut.For detailed instructions on how to use it, check this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/900716/configure-keyboard-shortcut-to-enable-disable-chrome-extension)